# converting list with hex string and integers to string in python, scapy

Tags: python, dns, scapy

I used scapy to create DNS response and pass it to LZW to compress it. After the compression I got the following list.

```
['f', '\xa5', '\x84', '\x00', '\x00', '\x01', '\x00', '\x06', '\x00', '\x04', 264, '\x03', 'w', 268, '\x06', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'g', 'l', 'e', '\x03', 'c', 'o', 'm', 259, 261, '\x01', 267, 269]
```

The list has values above 256 very frequently.
How could I convert this entirely to a hex string or how to convert it to scapy DNS packet so that I could send it.
hexilfy and hex wont work since there are integers in the list, I have tried both of these

Comment: are you saying the LZW library returns a list with both strings and ints in it?  Can you provide more sample code and an example of the resulting hex you would be expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert to unicode then encode with `utf-8` encoding , and for escape the int values use `isinstance` in a list comprehension :

```
>>> [unicode(i,'unicode-escape').encode('utf-8') if not isinstance(i,int) else i for i in l]
['f', '\xc2\xa5', '\xc2\x84', '\x00', '\x00', '\x01', '\x00', '\x06', '\x00', '\x04', 264, '\x03', 'w', 268, '\x06', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'g', 'l', 'e', '\x03', 'c', 'o', 'm', 259, 261, '\x01', 267, 269]
```

Comment: I need the output as hex string not list. Since I cannot use / operator with list. I cannot convert the above output to hex since it has integers. what I need is hex strings with integers converted to hex values as well. I am using the compression code mentioned here http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#Python

Comment: as you may now `hex()` just accept number so do you want to convert the ASCII code of your character to hex ?

Comment: I need the values above 255 to occupy two bytes. e.g value 508 to be displayed as 01 fc